# Deleting Duplicated Rows using CTE and getting "target DML table is not hash partitioned"

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, azure-synapse

We have a table with multiple columns and NO column ID. I am trying to delete duplicated rows when ALL columns are matched together. I found CTE to be helpful in this and managed to use it in our Azure SQL Server, but I am now getting the error on the same tables we have in our Synapse Pool:

> The query processor could not produce a query plan because the target
> DML table is not hash partitioned.

I am using this structure of code to delete duplicated rows:

```
   WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7] ORDER BY col1)
   FROM dbo.Table1
   )
   DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated with new method**:
I haven't been able to get the "DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1" format to work with the Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool. The only method I have found to work consistently is to create a new table from the original, drop the original, and then rename the new table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1_new
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7] ORDER BY col1)
    FROM dbo.Table1
) AS TMP
WHERE rn = 1;

-- Clean Up --
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
RENAME OBJECT dbo.Table1_new TO Table1;
```

**Old Method (I don't recommend)**:
Using CTE and EXISTS only works if there is a column that has different values for each row. If all row values are the same, the method below will delete all rows. I have also found the number of rows returned from this query to be inconsistent even with static data for tables with >100M rows.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7] ORDER BY col1)
    FROM dbo.Table1
    )

DELETE FROM dbo.Table1 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE AS C
    WHERE dbo.Table1.[col1] = C.[col1]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col2] = C.[col2]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col3] = C.[col3]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col4] = C.[col4]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col5] = C.[col5]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col6] = C.[col6]
    AND dbo.Table1.[col7] = C.[col7]
    AND dbo.Table1.[key_col] = C.[key_col]
    AND C.RN > 1
)
```

NOTE: I received syntax errors when giving dbo.Table1 an alias.

Comment: Be careful using this, as this will actually remove all rows that have been duplicated (without leaving 1 unduplicated row).

Comment: Atention., because this query will delete all id rows